# Notify of changes between controllers that may or may not exist

Tags: angularjs, publish-subscribe

If you have two area's on a page, i.e

```
<div ng-controller="LeftController">

</div>

<div ng-controller="RightController">

</div>
```

And lets say the `LeftController` can live and exist without the `RightController`. But should the `RightController` exist and something change ... then the `LeftController` needs to know about that change.

How can the `LeftController` know subscribe to those changes? Does that require a framework like Amplify or is this something that can be handled in Angular?

### Usecase

So the problem I'm solving is theres some tabs on the screen. The user may or may not have access to either tabs.

When the tab is loaded initially, it loads from the server.

Tab 2 (RightController) may load before Tab 1 (LeftController), if Tab 1 doesn't exist or isn't loaded yet, and Tab 2 publishes a change. Nothing happens. If Tab 1 is loaded, user goes to Tab 2, changes a value, that may affect the UI in Tab 1. So Tab 2 publishes that hes changed. Tab 1 now changes what he needs based on the new information.

Comment: You can use $rootScope service `$broadcast` method to communicate across such controllers. This can act as pub\sub mechanism.

Comment: See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/f733J/

Comment: In your scenario, if `LeftController` is not on the page, and `RightController` publishes.  Does `LeftController` need notification of the event when it is then loaded?  In other words, do you need durable pub/sub?  Or just pub/sub to all currently listening subscribers?

Comment: @davin nope. Its purely there for elemental reasons. If the user goes and enables widget with Left controller. Then it would render the information that was published when it comes from the server. Then would subscribe to changes now that it exists. Basically I don't  want to go to the server to check for changes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The is two ways to do this:

1. Using events (emit or broadcast in the scope)
2. Using a Service / Factory

I've made a plunker with these 2 options. I hope it help you.

[Plunker - Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/DtvxzTWwm0nWwEPJBUuX?p=preview)

Sources:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services

Comment: Awesomesauce. I like this example, makes sense! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a simple service and inject it to both controllers.

```
app.factory('myService', function() {
    var onMessageCallbacks = [];
    var onMessage = function(cb) {
        onMessageCallbacks.push(cb);
    };

    var newMessage = function(msg){
        for (var cb in onMessageCallbacks) {
            onMessageCallbacks[cb](msg);
        }
    };

    return {
        onMessage: onMessage,
        newMessage: newMessage
    };
});
```

First, you use `onMessage` to subscribe to events:

```
app.controller('LeftController',
    function LeftController($scope, myService) {
        myService.onMessage(function(receivedMsg){
            // do sth...
        });
    }
);
```

When one of the controllers wants to say something, use `newMessage`:

```
app.controller('RightController',
    function RightController($scope, myService) {
        myService.newMessage('Hello!');
    }
);
```

Comment: Why not use `$broadcast` and `$emit`?

Comment: Surely using `$broadcast` is much more simple and seems prettier. Advantage of this solution comes if you want to manipulate the passed data inbetween (ie. implementing some logic that controllers shouldn't be aware of).